# Calculate the mean for all the attributes of a zipcode?

Tags: csv, excel, statistics, zip-codes

I have a spreadsheet with two columns: Zipcode and Housing Price. Is it possible to calculate the average Housing Price per zipcode without manually using Excel commands per zip code?

Comment: e.g. python, R, name any scripting language as well as a couple of methods in excel itself I guess. I know zip codes are tempting to be thought of as spatial, but in this case, it seems to be a 'simple' table analysis, not strictly related to spatial data and therefor would be better suited for an other board...

Comment: An excel pivot table will do it. https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/show-averages-with-an-excel-pivot-table/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is with an excel pivot table. [Here’s a link to a blog](https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/show-averages-with-an-excel-pivot-table/).

If you want to do it do it in ArcGIS use [Summary Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm). Use your housing price field as the input field and choose MEAN as your statistics type. Use your zip code field as your case field.

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS you could do a *resume statistics* so you can calculate the mean of an attribute for each case of zip code. Just an idea.